# Why is it so warm in the Pacific Northwest of North America right now - mid April 2021?

Tags: meteorology, weather-forecasting

Temperatures are 5-7 degrees Celsius above average in southwestern British Columbia, and it's surreal for it to be so warm and sunny when the deciduous trees are still mostly barren.

Comment: https://ds.data.jma.go.jp/tcc/tcc/products/clisys/anim/GIF/tp/anom/2021/04/14/10day/SlpTempWind_tp_20210414.gif There is a ridge to the west of you over the NE Pacific which is causing subsidence

Comment: The ridge is probably related to t he block over at 120 W - https://www.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/products/precip/CWlink/blocking/real_time_nh/1panel_ghgs_obs_nh_nrm.gif

Comment: https://www.ncwlife.com/northcentral-washington-weather-conditions-are-setting-up-for-a-dry-and-windy-day/

Comment: it is april the time of year when you can have all four seasons in a couple of hours.

Comment: @spillthrill "Large blocking over southern BC " https://yubanet.com/regional/weekend-warming-trend-with-temperatures-15-to-20-degrees-above-normal/ my hypothesis is confirmed